# Add and retrieve metafield for shop information with shopify rest api

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Can add a metafield for shop with shopify api but can not retrive this metafield with shop information. How can retrieve this information with shop information. If I add this metafield info for specific order how I can retrieve this with order details.